# I keep getting the error, "Argument 1 missing or nil" and it doesn't give me a line number, so i have no clue what to do

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService") 
local Place = 1639914227
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter()
    if player then
        TeleportService:Teleport(Place, player)
    end
end)
```

the script is trying to use a click detector to teleport a player to another place from the main game

Answer (score 1):

`:GetPlayerFromCharacter` requires a Character (as the name implies). You're not giving it any arguments.

However, that's not necessary. `MouseClick` gives you the player that clicked the ClickDetector:

```
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    TeleportService:Teleport(Place, player)
end)
```

---

I'm skeptical that there is no line number for this particular mistake -- it should follow immediately after the error, as in

> 23:45:22.359 - Argument 1 missing or nil
>
> 23:45:22.360 - Stack Begin
>
> 23:45:22.361 - Script 'Workspace.Part.ClickDetector.Script', ***Line 4***
>
> 23:45:22.362 - Stack End